# Ways to show fractions

Tags: fractions

As I use `TexMaths` in LibreOffice and it has a problem with `\frac` and `\over`; are there other ways to show fractions in Tex?

In LibreOffice with `\frac` the line is not shown:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think your question may be borderline off-topic for this site. Can you tell us how you use `\frac` to typeset that fraction? Where do you put the braces, etc.?

Comment: that's a tex syntax question, by the way: [If you have a question about Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc. then you're in the right place to ask your question!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is on community whether they go on to the question of contruing the law or answering the current question, I'll leave, probably a downvote it will be delete the question automatically if you don't like it! ;)

Comment: Hi, just tried `\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}` in Libre Office 4.1.3 with TexMaths 0.38 and the fraction is printed correctly. What version are you on? If you're not on the latest version you should consider an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the "Transparency" option provided by TexMaths. It worked for me.